# Can I plug my charger in while updating ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, updating, ubuntu-13.10

I am updating to Ubuntu 13.10 today and my computer is running out of charge. Can I plug my charger in while it is updating? Will it mess up the update?

Comment: I would recommend you plug in the charger.  This does not usually interfere with what the computer is doing.  Conversely, if you let it run out of charge while updating, your system might be corrupted.

Comment: your power charger yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will mess up the update if the laptop battery it will discharge. So, you should plug your charger as quickly as possible. This is recommended from the start!